# How to prevent ALT text showing on cursor hover over image?

Tags: css

I know that ALT text is supposed to augment the image ... be of use to the visually impaired, etc, but I am thinking of Google Charts and want to use it as a warning ...

If the image can't be seen, for some reason, my ALT text is "Unable to create chart.  Check internet connection or report program error" (cos Google Charts is quite delicate & it's easy to feed it a chart description which it doesn't understand, in which case there is no image)

However, even if the image can me seen, some/many browsers show the ALT text when the cursor hovers over the image, which is confusing to the user.

So, since I'm not much of a CSS guru, how do I prevent the ALT text showing on cursor hover over a Google chart image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hovering over the image usually displays the value of the `title` attribute.  Maybe try explicity giving it an empty value.

```
<img src="myimg.jpg" alt="My Image" title="" />
```